# Issue with "edit" links on Menu pages

Tags: 7, routes, debugging

I have an unusual bug i've encountered during development of a client site -- it appears that for all Editable menus, when I click on edit, the site loops me into a Redirect Loop, pointing to a menu call I have for a custom module (see below). I'm not sure what the cause could be here, and there's a lot of code that needs to be sweeped through to determine the culprit.

I imagine if this is occuring in Admin, it could have consequences when we eventually hand the site over to the client. What are my best approaches to go about debugging this issue, starting with disabling offending modules?

The hook_menu() call for the routing rule that ultimately loads from the loop is below:

```
function example_checkin_menu() {
  $items['checkup'] = array(
    "title" => t("Checkin"),
    "page callback" => "drupal_get_form",
    "page arguments" => array('example_checkin_form'),
    "access arguments" => array('view check in form'), //Assigned to all roles
    "type" => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file' => "example_checkin.form.inc",
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Does the site use i18n?